# Error: Type 'SingleChildCloneableWidget' not found in Provider package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I updated Provider. Now it's not working

> lib/di/global_providers.dart:13:6: Error: Type 'SingleChildCloneableWidget' not found.
>   List globalProviders = [
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   lib/di/global_providers.dart:18:6: Error: Type 'SingleChildCloneableWidget' not found.
>   List independentServices = [
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   lib/di/global_providers.dart:23:6: Error: Type 'SingleChildCloneableWidget' not found.
>   List dependentServices = [
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   lib/main.dart:18:16: Error: The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.
>    - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
>    - 'SingleChildWidget' is from 'package:nested/nested.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/nested-0.0.4/lib/nested.dart').
>       providers: globalProviders,
>                  ^
>   lib/di/global_providers.dart:13:6: Error: 'SingleChildCloneableWidget' isn't a type.
>   List globalProviders = [
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   lib/di/global_providers.dart:18:6: Error: 'SingleChildCloneableWidget' isn't a type.
>   List independentServices = [
>        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   lib/di/global_providers.dart:23:6: Error: 'SingleChildCloneableWidget' isn't a type.
>   List dependentServices = [

Code

```
List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> globalProviders = [
  ...independentServices,
  ...dependentServices,
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> independentServices = [
  Provider.value(value: YelloChatDb()),
  Provider.value(value: YelloChatClient()),
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> dependentServices = [
  ProxyProvider<YelloChatDb, CategoryDao>(
      update: (context, yelloChatDb, categoryDao) => CategoryDao(yelloChatDb)),

  ProxyProvider<YelloChatDb, SubCategoryDao>(
      update: (context, yelloChatDb,subCategoryDao) => SubCategoryDao(yelloChatDb)),

  ProxyProvider<YelloChatDb, UserDao>(
    update: (context, yelloChatDb, userdAO) => UserDao(yelloChatDb),
  ),

  ProxyProvider<YelloChatDb, EnquiriesDao>(
    update: (context, yelloChatDb, enquiriesDao) => EnquiriesDao(yelloChatDb),
  ),

  ProxyProvider<YelloChatClient, CategoryService>(
      update: (context, yelloChatClient, categoryService) =>
          CategoryService.create(yelloChatClient.chopperClient),
      dispose: (context, categoryService) => categoryService.client.dispose()),


  ProxyProvider2<CategoryDao, CategoryService, CategoriesRepository>(
      update: (context, categoryDao, categoryService, categoryRepository) =>
          CategoriesRepository(categoryDao: categoryDao, categoryService: categoryService)),

  ProxyProvider2<UserDao, CategoryService, UserRepository>(
      update: (context, userDao, categoryService, categoryRepository)=>
          UserRepository(userDao: userDao, categoryService: categoryService)
  ),

  ProxyProvider2<SubCategoryDao, CategoryService, SubCategoriesRepository>(
      update: (context, subCategoryDao, categoryService, subCategoryRepository) =>
          SubCategoriesRepository(categoryDao: subCategoryDao, categoryService: categoryService)),

  ProxyProvider2<EnquiriesDao, CategoryService, EnquiriesRepository>(
      update: (context, enquiriesDao, categoryService, enquiriesRepository) =>
          EnquiriesRepository(enquriesDao: enquiriesDao, categoryService: categoryService))
];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From **Provider v4.0.0**

The `SingleChildCloneableWidget` interface is removed, and replaced by a `SingleChildWidget` interface and two implementations:

- SingleChildStatelessWidget
- SingleChildStatefulWidget

`MultiProvider` will accept a `SingleChildWidget` instead of `SingleChildCloneableWidget`.

See this [issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/237) in GitHub.

Answer (score 5):

*Try*

```
import 'package:provider/single_child_widget.dart';
```

And Replace

```
List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> independentServices
```

with

```
List<SingleChildWidget> independentServices
```

It works. I have checked with dependency provider: `^4.3.2+3`

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I would not recommend doing that. Consider creating this list directly inside your MultiProvider.

Doing what you're currently doing adds unnecessary complexity & ceremony for no real benefits.
In fact you're actually decreasing testability.

If you insist on doing that though, the Readme is pretty clear about it:

Replace SingleChildCloneableWidget by SingleChildWidget (from provider/single_child_widget.dart)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "you're actually decreasing testability" ?